# After register new assembly in GAC, Visual Studio doesn't find any dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, global-assembly-cache

I've registered some assemblies to Global Assembly Cache executing the following the command at Visual Studion Command Prompt.

```
gacutil /il MyAssemblyList.txt
```

After that, I can't compile anything in Visual Studio, because It can't find any DLL.
When I try to compile a Silverlight project it gives me this kind of error message:
"Error  4   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. "

I have updated all the references and the text editor show no errors.

Can someone help?

Update: I repaired .NET Framework installation and the problem still occurs

Comment: What's the content of 'MyAssemblyList.txt'?

Comment: These things are not strongly related, the compiler doesn't use the GAC for reference assemblies.  Unless you really screwed it up by overwriting a core assembly that the compiler itself needs to get its job done.  Hard to imagine what that might be.

Comment: @LuisFilipe a list of assemblies (complete path) of ComponentOne Studio For Silverlight

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think I have overwritten assemblies like System.Windows because the list only have ComponentOne assemblies.

Comment: It's funny how the GAC's original intent was to solve the DLL hell :-)

Comment: Well, that was my point.  Nor does the compiler *use* the GAC for System.Windows, the reference assemblies come from c:\program files\reference assemblies.  I can only conclude that you are chasing the wrong source of the problem.

Comment: Are you using Silverlight 5 ? Have you recently updated from silverlight 4 to 5 ?

Comment: @Oliver I'm using Silverlight 5 and its not recent.

Comment: @HansPassant I had to do a Revert operation (svn) because there is a very close deadline. After that, everything works fine, but with the old C1 assemblies. I'll try again later this night. Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, an SVN revert isn't going to restore the GAC so you are definitely on the wrong track with this.  Contact ComponentOne for support.

Answer (score 2):

When .NET tries to load an assembly its details can be viewed in an application called 'fuslogvw' - just run the VS Command Prompt and type

```
fuslogvw
```

After that, run your program til right after the assemblies are trying to be loaded.

Press 'Refresh' in the fuslogvw GUI and you should see one or more entries related to the culprit assemblies. Double click to see where .NET tried to load the assembly.

You may have to check 'settings' before and run it with Administrator privileges.

If you need further assistance paste the content of the details for us to give it a look

Comment: How do I run the VS command prompt?  Where do I find the VS command prompt?